# Javascript - Create own bookmark website with prompt?

Tags: javascript, prompt, bookmarks

I just started to learn Javascript and basically I wanted to create a bookmark on Google Chrome where I basically just want to do:

*"www.hello" + i + ".com"*

so basically open up a prompt where I myself enter what I want "i" to be and then it should then add up so etc:

*i = world*

*end: www.helloworld.com (Automatic open it up).*

I assume this is beginner level but I have just learned and I just know how to open up a prompt at this moment.

```
javascript:(()=>{let i=prompt("Enter "i" for website ,")
```

and now I dont know how to continue to make it add for a website.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage

Comment: For starters, you'll have to escape the double quotes around i in that string with backslashes. `"Enter \"i\" for website"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's very simple..

Just copy paste the code below and save it in your bookmark and give it a try..

```
javascript:var websiteName = prompt("Enter \"i\" for website..");var url = "http://www.hello"+websiteName+".com";window.location.href = url;
```

Note that `javascript:` at the front will be automatically removed when you copy and paste the code manually in url bar. So save it once in bookmark and use.

Comment: Oh okey! That looks nice, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much use whatever you would normally put between `<script>` tags on your page. So this:

```
var i = prompt("Enter website:", "");
if (i == null || i == "") {
    //add whatever action you would like when user cancels
} else {
    window.open("https://www."+ i +".com");
}
```

Becomes this (minus the comments):

```
javascript: var i = prompt("Enter website:", ""); if (i == null || i == "") { } else { window.open("https://www."+ i +".com"); }
```